# Looking for a concordance for agape & phileo in all their forms

Tags: love

I've been looking at usages of agape and phileo in the NT. It's been difficult because both are typically translated "love" in English. I've tried doing searches against the Greek text via Bible Gateway but I have to specify every form separately.

Is there somewhere that I can get a concise list list of references for each term?

Comment: Logos can do it with a Lemma search. Look for the ability to do a Lemma search where you try.

Comment: If you can get an electronic version of the Greek text, a search for " ἀγαπ" or " φιλ" will find all words that start with the substring.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest is Bible Hub with the following short-cuts:

- ἀγαπάω (agapaó) — 143 Occurrences  https://biblehub.com/greek/strongs_25.htm
- ἀγάπη (agapé) — 116 Occurrences  https://biblehub.com/greek/strongs_26.htm
- ἀγαπητός (agapétos) — 61 Occurrences  https://biblehub.com/greek/strongs_27.htm
- φιλέω (phileó) — 25 Occurrences  https://biblehub.com/greek/strongs_5368.htm
- φίλος (philos) — 29 Occurrences  https://biblehub.com/greek/strongs_5384.htm

There are many more resources on this site.

Comment: Not all forms of agape are in this list. Anyway, searching for each form is what I was trying to avoid.

Comment: A lemma search is equivalent to the above.

Answer (score 0):

Blueletter Bible is my personal favorite.

https://www.blueletterbible.org/

The search function works in the 'normal' way (plain English lookup for a word or a verse reference).  Once there though, if you hover over the "TOOLS" button and select "Interlinear," you get a word-by-word breakout with the Hebrew/Greek text.  These have links that take you to individual Strong's references, much the same as the Bible Hub URLs that Mac's Musings supplied.  E.g.,

https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=G25&t=KJV

From these entries you can "drill down" to the specific variations of each word.

Comment: As I mentioned in the OP, searching for every variation is what I'm trying to avoid. I'm a little surprised that none of these resources offer a search against the root.

Comment: @blearyeye, the sample page I included a link to, aggregates all the forms together in one block of search results.  From that 'main' set of results you can drill down to specific forms, if you choose.  But the default is to return all the forms in one search.