# ἀγαπάω vs. φιλέω

Tags: love, agape, phileo

Regarding John 21:15-17 and the use of ἀγαπάω vs. φιλέω, I've often heard preachers say “ἀγαπάω” is divine and “φιλέω” is human.  But this always made me wonder about John 3:17, “men ἀγαπάω darkness rather than light.”

Proverbs 8:17 uses אהב twice, a word (ahab/agab) which **may** be related to ἀγαπάω, but the Septuagint uses ἀγαπάω once and φιλέω once.  (I’m not a scholar of either language and if I have the inflection wrong, it’s because I copied the words from Strong’s dictionary.)

**What explanations (hypotheses) are there about the implications of these two words in these passages?**  (Including speculations on why the seventy(-two) translators used two different Greek words for one Hebrew word.)

Comment: Feel free to put better tags on this.  But please refrain from any discussion of the fact that "17" is in all three references. :-)

Comment: the popular notion that agape is divine and special is a modern myth of the misguided preachers https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/79211/agape-and-phileo Agape simply means the benevolence/love in the sense of embracing someone as family, as our own; whereas philos means friendship, to like someone.

Comment: Do this question and answer answer your question? https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/31348/two-words-for-love-in-john-2115-17/44336#44336 and https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/31348/two-words-for-love-in-john-2115-17

Comment: Mine might be considered an almost duplicate of 31248 which is indeed very helpful (_all_ the answers except one).  79211, is also helpful, though closed just because the OP didn't cite any specific verse.